Baking Textures with alpha and keeping the color Information
I use blender quite often to create Textures for game assets.
But sometimes I ran into a Baking Issue:
If a Game-Engine requires a packed texture with all the Color Channels used, the other Channels are getting darkened by the Alpha channel or completely removed if the alpha is too low.
Can I somehow tell blender to keep the Color information while baking textures?
Usually, I use the diffuse baking option with only the color enabled.

At which step it removes the color information?

The Baked image does not have the color information of the "transparent" mesh parts.

Plug the output socket with the data you want to an Emission node and bake it as the Emit bake type directly. Emit does not alter the output. The Cycles' diffuse is not a diffuse texture in the PBR sense. It is a diffuse component of the Cycles' internal calculations.

Currently I've use this Workaround:
I bake the RGB into an Image, and the Alpha into a Second.
Then I use the Composite Nodes to combine them into a RGBA Texture.
